# How to refresh Event data in Jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Im Trying to reload my event data(JSON) when the viewDisplay function is called, not to sure how I call it tho?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            defaultView: '@Model.ScheduleView',
            editable: true,
            events: '/Schedule/GetSchedule',

            viewDisplay:function (view) {
                if (view.name == "resourceDay") {
//Call refresh of events to fire ('/Schedule/GetSchedule') <---- This line
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the refetchEvents() function:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/